# Is EntityFrameworks AddRange Method Transactional

Tags: entity-framework, transactional

When I use the `AddRange` method from the Entity Framework and then call `SaveChanges`, if one of the Entities fails to be inserted into the DB, will everything be rollbacked?

I don't want to use explicit Transactions.

Comment: It would be mostly irrelevant for `AddRange` to be "transactional" as it doesn't change the database state. The `SaveChanges` is, however, as @JavierVargas mentionned. I think you should either change the title not to be misleading, or change the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From msdn doc:

SaveChanges operates within a transaction. SaveChanges will roll back that transaction and throw an exception if any of the dirty ObjectStateEntry objects cannot be persisted.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792(v=vs.110).aspx

I hope it helps!